# Error building executable with cx_Freeze: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze, python-3.6

### Background

I have made a program that I am trying to turn into an executable using CX_Freeze. The `setup.py` file is placed inside the same directory as all files I am working with. I don't use any extra libraries other than TKinter and OS.

The program works perfectly fine normally when I run it via *PyCharm>Run*

---

### Version Numbers

- *cx_Freeze ver:* - 5.0
- *cx_Freeze .whl:* - cx_Freeze-5.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
- *python ver:* - 3.6.0b4
- *pycharm ver:* - 2016.3.1

---

### This is my `setup.py` file

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "FileOrganizer-Client",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter","os"],"include_files":["icon2.ico"]}},
    version = "0.01",
    description = "File Organizer",
    executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("alpha_GUI.py", base=base, icon="icon2.ico")]
)
```

---

### This is the error I get when I run "python setup.py build" inside the directory

```
C:\Users\Jeremy\PycharmProjects\cleanup>C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python setup.py build running build running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "setup.py", line 18, in
<module>
    executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("alpha_GUI.py", base=base, icon="icon2.ico")]

  File
"C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py",
line 349, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)

  File
"C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\core.py",
line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()

  File
"C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py",
line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)

  File
"C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py",
line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()

  File
"C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\command\build.py",
line 135, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)

  File
"C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\cmd.py",
line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File
"C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\distutils\dist.py",
line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()

  File
"C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py",
line 219, in run
    freezer.Freeze()

  File
"C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py",
line 621, in Freeze
    self.finder = self._GetModuleFinder()

  File
"C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py",
line 333, in _GetModuleFinder
    self.path, self.replacePaths)

  File
"C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py",
line 150, in __init__
    self._AddBaseModules()

  File
"C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py",
line 161, in _AddBaseModules
    self.IncludeModule("traceback")

  File
"C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py",
line 651, in IncludeModule
    namespace = namespace)

  File
"C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py",
line 310, in _ImportModule
    deferredImports, namespace = namespace)

  File
"C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py",
line 403, in _InternalImportModule
    parentModule, namespace)

  File
"C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py",
line 474, in _LoadModule
    self._ScanCode(module.code, module, deferredImports)

  File
"C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\finder.py",
line 562, in _ScanCode
    arguments.append(co.co_consts[opArg])

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

---

I am not very skilled or familiar with any of this so I hope I didn't leave anything out. Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been submitted as [a bug in `cx_freeze`](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues/215/cx_freeze-with-python-360rc1), Python 3.6 has introduced some changes to code objects (most notably with `PEP 523`) so it might have introduced certain bugs in applications that depend on them.

Keep track of the issue on `cx_freeze` and remember that certain errors might pop up when using a newly released version of Python.

---

As an aside, since you import `cx_Freeze` and access `setup` and `Executable` through there, there's no need for the:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
```

line. You aren't using those names.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it! using Python34 worked. I usually try to download the latest version of whatever language so I won't have to update as soon but I can see now how that isn't always a good thing. I have learned my lesson. :)

Comment: @JeremyWeisener you had downloaded the second release candidate of Python 3.6, not the `final` one! Either way, yes, you need to be careful (btw, pretty sure Python 3.5 would also work w/o issue.

Comment: Ahh, it was the only one I saw. =X I had python 3.4 installed already so I just chose to use that. It is very basic code.